# Matlab plot multiple figures without window

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot with hidden Matlab figures to speed up my plotting:

```
a=1:10; b=-a;
% make invisible plot window 
f = figure('visible','off');
g = figure('visible','off');

% figure makes the plot visible again    
figure(f)    
plot(a)
saveas(f,'newout','fig')

figure(g)
plot(b)
saveas(g,'newout2','fig')

%% load saved figures    
openfig('newout.fig','new','visible')
openfig('newout2.fig','new','visible')
```

The problem is the **figure(f)** command that makes the plot window visible again.
The code plots without figure window when I only have one plot and figure(f) is not called.

Comment: see the tips section in the figure's help (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just learned that instead of calling `figure(f)` one should use set:

```
set(0, 'currentfigure', g);
```

This will change the current figure handle without changing its visibility.
The corrected version works as expected:

```
a=1:10; b=-a;
% make invisible plot window 
f = figure('visible','off');
g = figure('visible','off');

% figure makes the plot visible again    
set(0, 'currentfigure', f);
plot(a)
saveas(f,'newout','fig')

set(0, 'currentfigure', g);
plot(b)
saveas(g,'newout2','fig')

%% load saved figures
close all
openfig('newout.fig','new','visible')
openfig('newout2.fig','new','visible')
```

Comment: That's good to know! Can you accept your answer so that the thread is closed?

Comment: Yes, but only after 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a whole new plot window. By doing that you will get two different plots, and as you say that only one plot works, i think it could work.

Comment: I already have two plots ,f and g, and want to switch between them without changing their visibility.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to *reference the axes* within the `plot` command (instead of changing the current figure before `plot`):

```
a=1:10; b=-a;
f = figure('visible','off');
fax = gca; %// get handle to axes of figure f
g = figure('visible','off');
gax = gca; %// get handle to axes of figure g

plot(fax, a) %// plot in axes of figure f
saveas(f,'newout','fig')

plot(gax, b)  %// plot in axes of figure g
saveas(g,'newout2','fig')

openfig('newout.fig','new','visible')
openfig('newout2.fig','new','visible')
```